# application ajax time out

Tags: ajax, spring-mvc

Controller:
The code that handles post back has a db call in biz layer that is long running. After 30 minutes, the browser showed the error message from the ajax call, however my db logs showed that the db method was still running - ran way past the 30 min mark.

My ? is how does the ajax error get raised when it wasn't raised in the controller [log4j did not show any errors trapped] as the controller was still waiting for feedback from the biz layer.

Does adjusting the timeout in tomcat help? I assume not as the app was still processing

My View:

```
function runAjax(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Test.html",
        data: { testparam1,testparam2},
        success: function(data){
            document.getElementById("processdata").innerHTML="Success";
        },
        error: function(request){
            document.getElementById("processdata").innerHTML="Error";
        }
        });
}
```

Comment: Yes, you need to fix this server-side.

Answer (score 0):

The browser, aka JavaScript, is not going to wait forever for a response.  After some time (read 30min in this case), it will give up on the request, thinking the server is not responding.  HTTP is not really set up to handle requests that take > 30min, at least not through the normal means.

There are some options.  First, you could optimize whatever you are doing in the backend to make it faster.  I mean, if it's taking 30+ min for a query to run, then you may need to rethink your SQL approach a bit.

Second, you could simply break up the steps, so that you can run each step, verify, then run the next.  Depending on what you are doing, this may open up the possibility to do some work in parallel, speeding up the process.  The challenge here would be in rolling back in the case when something failed.

Third, you could implement a Pub/Sub model.  There are several frameworks out there to do Pub/Sub for JavaScript.  I have personally used Atmosphere, which has a nice jQuery plugin and falls back to more HTTP conventional methods when the more advanced methods are not available in the browser.  In this model, your View would submit the request, the backend would queue up the work and tell the View to subscribe to a particular queue/channel to get the result.  The View can simply wait for the response.

Forth, you could post the request, have an interrum page that simply keeps refreshing via JavaScript until the backend says "Ok, we are done!".  Lots of older web applications used to do this for long-running transactions.

I am sure there are probably 1000 more options you could use, but if your request will always take that long to run, I think AJAX is not the tool for you.